# In a job template, how can I change the job name depending on the template parameters?

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have a job template:

```
parameters:
- name: is_release_version
  type: boolean
  default: false

jobs:
- job: 'Build'
  displayName: 'display name'
```

But I would like the job name to be "Build_Test" or "Build_Release" depending on my parameter.

I tried:

```
parameters:
- name: is_release_version
  type: boolean
  default: false

variables:
- ${{ if eq(parameters.is_release_version, false) }}:
  - name: name_ext
    value: Test
- ${{ if eq(parameters.is_release_version, true) }}:
  - name: name_ext
    value: Release

jobs:
- job: 'Build_${name_ext}'
  displayName: 'display name'
```

But "variables" is not expected at this level.
I tried passing the name directly as parameter and that works, but I would rather fix the possibilities in the template.

I also tried:

```
parameters:
- name: is_release_version
  type: boolean
  default: false

jobs:
- ${{ if eq(parameters.is_release_version, false) }}:
  - job: 'Build_Test'
- ${{ if eq(parameters.is_release_version, true) }}:
  - job: 'Build_Prod'
  displayName: 'display name'
```

But it does not work either. I guess the problem is the indentation of "displayName", and that would mean I would have to duplicate the whole job for the two if.

For now I will pass the name, but I am interested in any method to change the job name in a template.

Answer (score 3):

The variable called format you used in job name is not correct. You can try to use `Build_${{variables.name_ext}}`:

```
jobs:
- job: 'Build_${{variables.name_ext}}'
  displayName: 'Build_${{variables.name_ext}}'
```

See the execution result while I define `is_release_version value` as `true`:

[image]

You can see that it can pass `name_ext` value into job name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I had put ${} because I was defining the variable into the template itself. I currently do what you propose, but that mean I have to manually ensure my name variable and is_release_version variable are consistent.

Comment: @Pierre We do not have such `${}` format to get variable. For yaml, what we support are `${{}}` and `$()` and they are separately used for run time and compile time.  In addition, what does name variable and is_release_version need consistent mean? Isn’t that you are trying to define job name based on different is_release_version value?

Comment: @Pierre If anything misunderstood or missed, just free to correct.

Comment: you are right, I mixed ${} and $(). My problem with passing both the option and the name is that I could mix them up. Today I am using the template using:
`is_release_version: true / name_ext: Prod`
or:
`is_release_version: false / name_ext: Test`
but nothing prevents:
`is_release_version: false / name_ext: Prod`
Which would generate a wrongly labeled job.

Comment: @Pierre Can I consider as you want to pass dynamically value to template including is_release_version and the name_ext. Both of these 2 are all get from YAML? Not hard code in template.yml file?

Comment: @Marlin I would like to only pass is_release_version to the template and have the build name change depending on it.

Comment: @Pierre.But based on my understanding , your  YAML script that in second part has achieve what you want.

Comment: but my 2nd proposal is not valid as "variables" is not expected at this place, the yaml is rejected. I did not try to put the variable segment in the job part as I expected the variables would need to be setup before.

Comment: I tried to use `${{variables.some_var}}` where `some_var` is defined in a template on the stage scope. However it is not available in the job and returns as empty string. However if I pass the template at the job level then `some_var` is available in steps but not for the job name.